# My tablet is unsupported for a react-native android app

Tags: android, react-native

I am using a react-native android app. And my device is not supported because it does not have the required feature: android.hardware.telephony.

Yes, I do not have telephony in my tablet. But, I am not adding this required feature in my manifest. So, where exactly is react-native adding this required feature in the build? And how can I turn it off.

My manifest file is below.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kalhatti.main"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.5">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting in a uses-feature in your manifest with required=false?  To see if it overrides?

Comment: Setting it explictly to false in AndroidManifest did not work: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" required="false" />`

Comment: @GabeSechan It worked with `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />`. Please leave it as an answer and I can credit you as having answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow the app to be installed in tablets, add the following to AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Thanks to @GabeSechan for answering in comments.